# Magento 1: Use of <![CDATA in the system configuration XML

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, configuration, localisation, system.xml

I've noticed that **some comments in the native Magento 1 `system.xml` files are enclosed by `<![CDATA[` / `]]>` tags and some are not.**

For example in `app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/system.xml` we have:

```
<length translate="label comment">
    ...
    <comment>Please specify 8 symbols at the most. Range allowed (e.g. 3-5)</comment>
    ...
</length>
```

And:

```
<symbols translate="label comment">
    ...
    <comment><![CDATA[Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z) or numbers (0-9) in this field. No spaces or other characters are allowed.<br />Similar looking characters (e.g. "i", "l", "1") decrease chance of correct recognition by customer.]]></comment>
    ...
</symbols>
```

I first thought it could be because of HTML tags in the comment but in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml` we have:

```
<flat_catalog_product translate="label comment">
    ...
    <comment><![CDATA[Enable for reindexing a big number of SKUs]]>.</comment>
    ...
</flat_catalog_product>
```

So my questions are :

- **in which case one should use the CDATA tags in system configuration comments ?**
- **does the use of CDATA tags affect the translations** ? (understand do we have to write the CDATA tags in the translation files ?)

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: I would take a wild guess and say that is because you could have searched the purpose of CDATA online and tested yourself how it affects the translation by adding and removind the CDATA markup from one of the xml nodes....but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Marius well 2 downvotes now it escalates quickly.

Comment: I know the first ones are the most difficult. Been there, done that. You stop caring after the 5th one or so.

Comment: @Marius haha I don't mind the downvote, I just wish people would explain the reason so I could improve the next time instead of asking you to guess why the downvotes ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use CDATA to ensure the text inside it is not interpreted as XML/HTML.
But nobody restricts you to use it for every text tag.
The fact there is one or more uses of `CDATA` without having special chars in it may mean that someone overlooked this, or just copy pasted it from somewhere else and forgot to remove the `CDATA`.
You can use it as you wish.
The translation is not affected in any way by `CDATA`.
`CDATA` is ignored by the XML parser.
with or without it the array (or SimplexmlElement or any other format) will look like this:

```
array(
    'flat_catalog_product' => 
         array(
             'translate' => 'label copmment'
             'comment' => 'Enable for reindexing a big number of SKUs'
         )
)
```

Format may vary depending on the parser.

[More info on CDATA](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect).

Comment: So my first assumption was right re: special characters. I think I have too high standards regarding Magento and consistency. Thanks for the answer